# Add a value to text input field in custom options - frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, custom-options, frontend

I want to add a default value to text input field in custom options to pass the magento validation. I try to do this in javascript like that: `jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").attr('value', '--------');` But in some places I need to remove this value: `jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").attr('value', '');` and when I use this last code, I have: `Please specify the product's required option(s).`

Thank you

Comment: you could specify by id instead of class so you can differentiate between which input textboxes need a value

Comment: Hi Anja, yes this was problem :) you save my life, please add your answer, I will vote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could specify by id instead of class so you can differentiate between which input textboxes need a value

i.e. instead of `jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").attr('value', '--------');` you could use something like `jQuery(".product-options dd input#youridhere").attr('value', '--------');`